# although export gg I got unbound variable gg

Tags: linux, bash

> include.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -

export gg

f() {
    for i in "${gg[@]}"
    do
        echo $i
    done
}
```

> run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -

set -o nounset

. include.sh || exit 1

f
```

I get this error

```
scripts/include.sh: line 5: gg[@]: unbound variable
```

Isn't `export` keyword supposed to make gg global and available anywhere?
If not, how to make gg available everywhere from `include.sh` ?

**UPDATE**

Environment:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="11.4"
VERSION_ID="11.4"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4"
```

Comment: I think you have `set -u` option set somewhere to throw errors on undefined variable access

Comment: It's `set -o nounset`, I just updated my question

Comment: Pertinent: [BashFAQ #112: What are the advantages and disadvantages of `set -o nounset`?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112). From that: *An empty array becomes an error (in bash 4.3, but not in bash 4.4, where there is no error even without assignment `array=()`)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legacy Unix shells don't support `()` arrays. You should invoke the scripts with `bash` and they'll run as expected.

As written in the updated question, you need to define `gg` before exporting it:

```
gg=()
export gg
```

I tested the patch and it works fine.

Comment: I updated my question. Although I removed `()`, I still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

If you `source` a file (equivalent to `.`), the commands are executed in the current shell context, therefore there is no need for `export`. However, using unset/empty array will cause `bash` to terminate your script if you are using `set -o nounset`. Either assign some values to your array:

```
gg=(value1 value2) #can be assigned in both run.sh and/or include.sh

f() {
    for i in "${gg[@]}"; do
       echo "$i"
    done
}
```

Or use parameter expansion to handle this:

```
f() {
   for i in ${gg[@]+"${gg[@]}"}; do
      echo "$i"
   done
}
```

`${parameter+word}` will expand to `word` only if `parameter` is set, otherwise *nothing* is substituted. If you want to read more about how this works with arrays: [wiki.bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_an_alternate_value).

---

As mentioned by @CharlesDuffy, in `bash 4.4` empty array doesn't become an error. There is no error even without assignment `array=()`. For more information, see:
 [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112).

Comment: It's probably worth discussing how bash 4.3 and bash 4.4 behavior differ wrt. `nounset` and arrays.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Great suggestion. May I include it in my answer, I don't want to just copy your comment...

Comment: Feel free to incorporate as you see fit -- you've got a good answer here as it is, there's no point in me trying to compete with it w/ only a minor addition.